# Creating alarm with AlarmManager for a specific period of time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

Is there any way to use AlarmManager to activate an alarm for a specific period of time? I have start-time and end-time values stored in the database. I want to start an alarm at start-time that will make the device silent and alarm should end at end-time when the device volume will be normal again.

One way is set alarm at start-time & then set another alarm at end-time. But the problem is **the time period may overlap** that will need additional logic to be implemented if I go with 2 different alarms(one at start-time, another at end-time). Is there any procedure in Android to cope with this situation? Or implementing logic is the only way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just in your `Intent` for the `PendingIntent` pass an extra like "endTime" long type for the time you want to end the alarm. (im assuming its repetitive) then in your broadcast receiver get that extra, compare to `System.currentTimeMillis()` and if it is less then current time cancel the alarm and exit?

Comment: Can you please explain how it can solve the overlapping timeslot problem that I am currently facing?

Comment: I guess i dont understand this issue, could you explain it a little more?

Comment: @jugernaut - User inputs some time intervals (start-time & end-time), the phone will be in silent-mode at that intervals. Problem is - suppose **user inputs 2 interval where intervals overlap each other**, i.e. 10AM-12PM & 11AM-2PM. In that case, issue raises as AlarmManager implements first alarm at 10AM & then at 11AM it again tries to implement silent mode. But the phone is already silent. at 12PM, the phone will be normal by the first interval but at the same time, second interval wants that phone will be silent until 2PM. So we need to implement some logic.

Comment: I just wanted to know, is there any way to implement this feature? I am gonna add a new prompt where users are informed about the overlapping & asked to change new one/overwrite existing one. Maybe this is the best option for now.